# Token expired while password reset

Tags: react-native, meteor

**methods.js(server-side)**

```js
resetPin: function(callback) {
    let user = Meteor.users.findOne({ username: "8390883758" });
    let data = Accounts.sendResetPasswordEmail(user._id);
    let token = user.services.password.reset.token;
    return token;
}
```

**ForgotPin.js (client-side)
on button press**

```js
changePin = () => {
    Meteor.call("resetPin", (err, tkn) => {
        console.log(tkn);
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else {
            Accounts.resetPassword(tkn, "123456", err => {
                if (err) console.log(err);
                else {
                    console.log("password reset done");
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

**expected output -**

password reset successfully

**actual output -**

```js
{
  isClientSafe: true, 
  error: 403, 
  reason: "Token expired", 
  message: "Token expired [403]", 
  errorType: "Meteor.Error"
}
```

**versions**

```js
meteor - 1.5.1   
node - 9.5.0  
react-native - ^0.47.1   
accounts-password- 1.4.0   
meteor-base - 1.1.0
```

Comment: How are you binding the `tkn` generated from the `resetPin` to the `resetPassword`? , Can you post the complete module?

Answer (score 1):

If you're copying your reset password link from the email logged to terminal, you need to remove the `=` at the end of the first line.

[image]

In this example, the full reset password URL would be `http://localhost:3005/reset-password/Yp1gp3gUMgNPfozpoxc_S4SIy4v3BTOLl1gYsv_pirG`.